# How to do benchmark on CGO tcp server?

Tags: go, benchmarking, cgo, pprof

I finished a TCP server by using CGO. Now I wish to do some benchmark analysis and optimization.

The connection flow across Go and C is as follows:

```
user <--> connFD <--> socketpair[0] <--> socketpair[1] <--> intranet server
|---------- Go domain ----------------|-------------- C domain -----------|
```

and the server only able to run in a docker container.

I tried using pprof to analysis a few seconds connection with real user I/O, however it gives me nothing:

```
(pprof) tree
Showing nodes accounting for 0, 0% of 0 total
----------------------------------------------------------+-------------
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%   calls calls% + context

(pprof) top
Showing nodes accounting for 0, 0% of 0 total
      flat  flat%   sum%        cum   cum%
```

Thus I would like to know is pprof only be able to analyze pure Go program? How can I do benchmarks on such a program properly?

Comment: Not sure if this helps, its not about benchmarking but profiling https://jvns.ca/perf-zine.pdf

Comment: Cgo is completely different from go, as far as i known you can't profile or benchmark cgo programs.

Comment: @Kyslik Thanks a lot! It helps a lot on profiling.